# What is the optimal and efficient way to warm a concave body on plain source of heat (heating concave pita)

Tags: thermodynamics

What is the optimal way to warm a concave body: placing it on the lowest point or opposite for optimally warming it? Optimally in this case is that the whole body will be heated and in the shortest time. The concave body is placed on plain source of heat. Imagine a concave pita that is place over a plain stove. If the heat source is not a plain, but microwave, what is the best position for heating the concave body?